# Problem databinding with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

Been beating my head against a wall and figured it was time to post a question.  I have the following user control

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WorkDayManager3.WPF.UserControls.TimeControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="46" d:DesignWidth="133" Background="Transparent"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">    
<Grid Height="44" Width="132" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="29" />            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="label" Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class TimeControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {

        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }

        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }

    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =

    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TimeControl), new UIPropertyMetadata("N/A"));

    public TimeControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In the Window where i use the control it is used in a grid with its datacontext set to a StaticResource

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{StaticResource shiftViewSource}" Name="grid1" Margin="48,10,38,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" TabIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,5" Name="shiftNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ShiftName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <my2:TimeControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" TabIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,5" Name="shiftNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ShiftName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <my2:TimeControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="THIS WORKS OK"/>            
    </Grid>
```

Now the TextBox that is Bound to Path ShiftName works fine and displays the text.  When i use my control instead it doesn't show the expected text.  However in the second example where i just set the Text dependency property to "THIS WORKS OK" the text shows up as expected.  Why does the binding work for the TextBox but not my control.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding DataContext = this; in your TimeControl constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've set the `DataContext` on the `UserControl` to itself. Thus, the binding of your `TimeControl`'s `Text` property is attempting to find a property called `ShiftName` on your `TimeControl`, not on your static resource. If you look in the output window of visual studio, you should see an error message to that effect.

It is never a good idea to set the `DataContext` on the `UserControl` anyway, because anyone could override it. You could just do this instead:

```
<UserControl x:Name="root" ...>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}"
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way might be to use a Relative binding:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" >
    ...
```